# Unsure about two phrases dealing with location

Tags: sentence-construction, phrases

I came up with these two phrases:

> There isn't a mall in the same city as this bakery.

and

> There's no "Louis" barber in the mall belonging to same city as this bakery.

With the first one I would like to say that, in a certain city, there is a bakery (at least one) but no mall (at all).

With the second one I'm trying to say that in a certain city there is a bakery (at least one) and that in the same city there's also a mall (only one). And that in this mall there's no barber advertised as "Louis".

I can't avoid to feel that they are somewhat awkward. The second one feels especially awkward.

Do you think they could be rearranged to feel more natural?

Comment: It sounds like you are attempting to answer a question. It would be helpful to know, or the larger context in which you are saying these phrases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence

> There isn't a mall in the same city as this bakery.

could be better phrased as

> The bakery is in a city that has no mall.

---

The second awkward sentence

> There's no "Louis" barber in the mall belonging to same city as this
>   bakery.

could be

> The bakery is in a city that does not have a "Louis"
>   barber in the mall.

Comment: Your versions are much better, thanks. I thought I'd wait about a day before accepting an answer.